# Greasemonkey script to get user comment from notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey

These days, I was wondering if I can make use of GreaseMonkey to create a user script which has the potential to repair an unusual bug present in some of social media sites with heavy trafic. What's this bug about?

Sometimes, just sometimes, when you get a notification that tells you "user X has commented/reply to your post/comment" and when you click it to after see that comment in your post, you notice the comment of that respective person doesn't appear in the comment section, even when you try to refresh the page. That's one side of the bug, sometimes you see the comments but when you refresh the page, they dissapear. Even your own comments dissapear...

My intention is to make a script which simply gets the comment someone has leave in your post/thread in that exact moment and appends them in a new section you create( which i hope that section won't be affected by the site bug) when you click the notification you got. Let's say, when i try to click the notification here on StackOverflow when someone leaves a comment on my post, a small new section at bottom-right appears and inside has the comment of respective person. The problem i'm facing is that I have no idea how to get the user comment, since it doesn't appear anywhere yet in the DOM tree when you get notified, only when you click "show comment".

My question is: Can this be done somehow with Javascript in GreaseMonkey ?

This is how the code looks when you get notified:

```
<div class="notification-list viewport">
            <ul class="overview" id="jsid-header-notification-items-container" style="top: 0px;">

                <li class="badge-evt with-thumb" data-evt="Notification-Menu,Clicked-Notification,/gag/a251nde?ref=w.commentmentionnoti#cs_comment_id=c_147059709823636409">
<a class="item new badge-unread-notification-item" href="/gag/a251nde?ref=w.commentmentionnoti#cs_comment_id=c_147059709823636409" target="_blank" data-objectid="http://9gag.com/gag/a251nde#c_147059709823636409" data-actiontype="COMMENT_MENTION">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

On that site, the comments someone leaves in your thread/post, doesn't show in the notification like how they are shown partial here on StackOverflow and so, not in the DOM tree. To view the comment someone writed, you must click the notification which will redirect you to the thread/post someone mentioned you and read his comment there, in the comment section. If it still exist, of course..

Comment: I don't think this has a singular answer, hence a comment: it _might_ be possible. It will probably vary from site to site in regards to feasibility and ease. It would most definitely not be a generic userscript you can just have on any site - it'd need to be tailor made for each.

Comment: @Vld I'm aware of that and I don't have in mind to make one script to work for all social media sites. For moment, I resume to one site i use to visit often and try to see if I can repair this annoying bug. I only need to know how can I get the user comment from notification.

Comment: " I only need to know how can I get the user comment from notification" that's the hard part. This will vary wildly from website to website, however, in general it's be some sort of communication with the server where the client will get any new comments/notifications/etc. You'll have to find out how the communication is done (most likely AJAX) and then find a way to tap into it. And also an additional layer of complexity might be handling the response that comes back if the format is a bit odd or something. Overall, not easy, as I said. The rest will probably be easier by comparison.

Comment: @BrockAdams I read your comment few minutes ago and I edited my question. Sorry for not providing much more details for the problem i'm facing. I thought this will have a fixed solution and no more details were needed. If you still want more info, I'm here.